# How to avoid error while executing Lua script

Tags: lua, scrapy-splash

I'm learning data scraping using Splash/Lua but the instructor not reply anymore. Ok Here is the Problem. I'm facing the error when I `splash.private_mode_enabled = false` but when it's True it's working fine but I've to disable this private mode and make it false.
Website URL - https://web.archive.org/web/20200116052415/https://www.livecoin.net/en/

HTTP Error 400 (Bad Request)
Type: ScriptError -> LUA_ERROR
Error happened while executing Lua script

Lua error: [string "function main(splash, args) ..."]:7: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

```
{
    "error": 400,
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
    "info": {
        "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]",
        "line_number": 7,
        "error": "attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)",
        "type": "LUA_ERROR",
        "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:7: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)"
    }
}
```

That's my lua script -

```
function main(splash, args)
  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
    url = args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  rur_tab=assert(splash:select_all(".filterPanelItem___2z5Gb "))
  rur_tab[5]:mouse_click()
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  return splash:png()
end
```

I'm looking for someone who can pointing the problem and how to solve it if they know.

Comment: Well, don't index a nil value. What is rur_tab and can you confirm that both rur_tab and its fifth element is not nil?